# Explanation Try;Catch;

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm still new to exception handling and this "try" and "catch" inside the method is way over my noobie skills.

Can someone explain to me what the "try" does?

```
public String getNif() {
    String cadenaNif = null;  
    char letraNif = ' ';      
    boolean letraCorrecta = true;
    try {
        letraNif = calcularLetraNif(this.numeroDni);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        letraCorrecta = false;
    }
    if (letraCorrecta) {
        cadenaNif = Integer.toString(numeroDni) + String.valueOf(letraNif);
    }
    return cadenaNif;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Comment: yea, there is no try or catch in there :(

Comment: @LoudMicro: just click the 'Next' link at bottom of the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what try is doing here is....

Its making your code safe to run... if any exception occurs it is caught by catch...
All the unsafe codes and anything we do are not sure of... we place that into try block...

If any exception occurs in processing the code in try block then catch block gets executed... There might be some (you can call dangerous) calculation happening in the line:

```
letraNif = calcularLetraNif(this.numeroDni);
```

hence it is placed in try block and a catch is accompanied to catch any dangerous outcome of that calculation.

For more info go to oracle docs exception handling.